# Softlayer Object Storage Python API Search

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I followed [softlayer-object-storage-python](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python) in order to return a list of my objects matching a specific criteria.

This code seems to just return everything in my container no matter what I put into the search

```
sl_storage = object_storage.get_client(
    username = environment['slos_username'],
    password = environment['api_key'],
    auth_url = environment['auth_url']
)

# get container
sl_container = sl_storage[environment['object_container']]

# get list, the search function doesn't actually work...
containers = sl_container.search("icm10restapi-qa.zip.*")
```

I expect only to get back things that start with icm10restapi-qa.zip.

I also tried using `^=icm10restapi-qa.zip` but no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the method, it seems that there is not possible to filter the objects as you would like:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python/blob/master/object_storage/client.py#L147

[API Operations for Search Services](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/API-Operations-Search-Services)

My apologizes for the inconveniences, I recommended to try filter these in your code.

> Updated

This script will help to filter your objects with the name which starts as specific string

```
import object_storage
import pprint

# Declare username, apikey and datacenter
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
DATACENTER = 'https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/'
# Creating object storage connection
sl_storage = object_storage.get_httplib2_client(USERNAME, API_KEY, auth_url=DATACENTER)
# Declare name to filter
name = 'icm10restapi-qa.zip'

# Filtering
containers = sl_storage.search(name)
for container in containers['results']:
    if container.__dict__['name'].startswith(name):
        print(container)
```

Comment: oh ok, thats fine.  what's the search do then?

Comment: See "Updated" section in my answer, I attached a script which will help you to filter

Comment: Hi, I was using something similar, however I've noticed something weird, I get duplicate items, or don't get those items at all sometimes.