# Softlayer Object Storage Wrong Search Results

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[Softlayer Object Storage Python API Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196616/softlayer-object-storage-python-api-search)

I basically have code the same as in the answer in the question above.  The zip_prefix is "restapi-qa.zip."

```
def get_cld_api_versions():
    # get next version from obj storage
    sl_storage = object_storage.get_client(
        username = environment['slos_username'],
        password = environment['api_key'],
        auth_url = environment['auth_url']
    )

    # get list, the search function doesn't actually work...
    containers = sl_storage.search(directories.local_cloudrestapi_prod["zip_prefix"])
    print directories.local_cloudrestapi_prod["zip_prefix"]
    apiversions = []
    for cont in containers['results']:
        print cont
        if cont.__dict__['name'].startswith(directories.local_cloudrestapi_prod["zip_prefix"]):
            apiversions.append(cont.name)

    return apiversions
```

Here are the results I get - it has duplicates and is missing icm10restapi_prod.zip

```
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.28, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-na1.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.23, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.25, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.29, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.30, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.22, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.26, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.27, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.26, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.27, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.31, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.12, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, testapi-qa.zip.32, 0B)
```

And other times I get these results - missing .26 and .27

```
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.28, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-na1.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.23, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.25, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.29, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-prod.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.30, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.22, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.31, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-prod.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi.zip, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.12, 0B)
StorageObject(testyi, restapi-qa.zip.32, 0B)
```

Here is the expected:

[image]

I have other files that are missing, as well sometimes, but I only pasted the above parts for brevity.

Comment: are you sure the zip_prefix is "icm10restapi-qa.zip".? because the objects in the response should start with: "icm10restapi-qa.zip" and not with "restapi..."

Comment: sorry i meant to edit out the prefix part, so it is supposed to be just restapi-qa.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't, take a look the following snapshot:

[image]

I was able to filter the objects which start with string "icm10restapi-qa.zip."

Comment: It's not that I can't filter it, its that the objects I get back before I filter are inconsistent - sometimes I get .zip.27, sometimes I dont.  What's the point of passing sl_storage.search(name) when the search doesn't work and I have to filter it anyways?

Comment: actually I removed .search(name) and just use .search(), and it seems to return all my items properly.

So when I had .search(name), it would return inconsistent results, sometimes with .zip.27, sometimes without.  However if I do .search(), it always returns everything, and I have to filter it manually anways.  I'm just really confused about the .search() function

Comment: Well... I'm not sure why are you facing this issue, please, try to add type property in search:
containers = sl_storage.search(name, type='object')

Comment: Let me know if you continue facing this issue

Comment: whats the point in doing .search(name) if I have to do .startswith(name) afterwards?

Comment: Because the search(name) will provide all objects which has "name" in the file names, so it means that it can not be always at the start of the name. for that reason I recommended to do "startswith(name)", in order to get objects which name start with a specific string

Comment: so that bug I encountered with inconsistent results seems to have disappeared, not sure why.  however the list I get back still has stuff like "cloudupgrader-qa.zip" and "icm.war".   I ended up using containers = sl_storage[environment['object_container']].objects() since I'm afraid of inconsistent results.  I don't have too many containers so it's pretty fast anyways.